# Solaris disks mirroring

Tags: virtualbox, solaris, disk

I have installed Solaris 11.3 on VirtualBox, but I have a problem.

I get the .ova file on Oracle WebSite but the disk size is not big and I need more space.

So, I want to create 2 disks and mirroring disk 1 with disk 2.

But when I create my second disk, he doesn't appear in /dev/dsk (c2d0), why please ?

PS : He is listed when I type 'format' command.

Comment: Are you using ZFS?

Comment: Just double checking here, but mirroring a small disk doesn't result on more available space; concatenating the second disk would, but isn't mirroring

Comment: I have created it with configuration -> storage on my Virtual Machine

Answer (score 0):

If the system didn't build the dev link, you'll need to run `devfsadm -v` to build.  I also like to toss in `-C` to also clean up the dev tree.  Aslo note that the dev tree on x86 is slightly different than SPARC for storage.

As Jeff Schaller mentions in a comment, mirroring to another drive would not give you any additional space.  That would/may give you some redundancy (assuming the 2nd drive served via VirtualBox is another device), so it might only help with ZFS being able to possibly repair data corruption.

If your goal is for more storage, you may just want to add a drive via virtualbox and create another zpool on it and create datasets on it as needed.

I haven't tried it, but I believe you can "grow" the storage on the virtualbox side.  If so, and you have the "autoexpand" option set on the pool, the pool will try to grow if there is more storage given on that slice.

`zpool get autoexpand rpool
NAME   PROPERTY    VALUE  SOURCE
rpool  autoexpand  off    default`

Another option is to enable compression on some of the datasets to help with data growth.  Just note, that currently on the boot dataset for the OS, you can't have a compression higher than "on," but I believe there is a RFE for this to be changed.